# Reduce Download Size of iOS App

Tags: ios

My app has several images and the app size on the store is 128 MB. I'm looking for a way to shrink the size of the app.  Are there any suggestions for PNG optimization tools?

Comment: Try http://tinypng.org to compress png image size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many Online tool available such as https://tinypng.com/, you can use them.